# Android bitmap deformed with strange lines and solid colors when loading into ImageView

Tags: android, bitmap, universal-image-loader

I am loading some bitmaps into image views, and sometimes one of them appears like so:

[image]

How is this problem called, so I know how to look for a solution in google?

This happens when there have been lots of bitmaps put into image views and memory has been low.

```
private void createBitmapAndSetItToImageView(final ImageAware imageAware, final int position, final boolean subsample) {

    if(subsample) {
        bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = 2;
    }
    bitmapInflateAsync = new BitmapInflateAsync(pathsList.get(position), bitmapOptions, new OnBitmapInflateFinishedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onBitmapInflateFinished(Bitmap bitmap) {
            setBitmapToImageView(imageAware, position, bitmap);
            if(subsample) {
                bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
            }
        }
    });
    bitmapWorkAsync.execute();
}

private void setBitmapToImageView(ImageAware imageAware, int position, Bitmap bitmap) {

    if (isAdded() && bitmap != null) {
        imageAware.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
     ....
}
```

Adding Universal image loader tag

Comment: Looks like you are using universal image loader. I would recommend using the universal-image-loader tag when posting questions related to this lib as the creator and maintainer probably has some insight as to what might be wrong.

Comment: okay, I will add this tag, but in third place, because I doubt the problem lies within the cast from ImageView to ImageAware

Comment: Does it happen on all test devices, and have you checked to see if the source image file is corrupt?

Comment: if i reload the fragment via onResume the image is displayed normally

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what caused the problem or how is it called, but I ended up finding what lead to it - I was using the same instance of Bitmap Options everywhere, which was being accessed by multiple threads and its parameters had often been changed dynamically.
When I stopped doing that and passed a brand new separate instance of Bitmap Options to each thread, the problem stopped occurring